# FirebaseApp in maven

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to get FirebaseApp from maven

in order to do:

```
 com.google.firebase.FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions =
                        FirestoreOptions.Builder()
                                .setDatabaseUrl("xxx")                   
 .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                                .build();

com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firestoreOptions);
```

but I don'k know which artifact to download

I have tried with:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

but the builder has `.setDatabaseId()` instead of `setDatabaseUrl()`

as I see in the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder#setDatabaseUrl(java.lang.String)

and the imports are

```
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions;
```

instead of

```
import com.google.firebase.Firestore;
import com.google.firebase.FirestoreOptions;
```

Comment: [firebase](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase) have many libraries, which one you are looking exactly in another word, what you want to do exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well document in [google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#java)

First of all you need to import this dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>6.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you are using gradle :

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.13.0'
}
```

And then your code should look like:

```
// Impots
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

// And code
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```